# Including base64 images from other files?

Tags: javascript, import, base64, webpack

At the moment I am using base64 images inside of my css and img tags through `data:` as you can imagine this can get really messy by including whole base64 code in a file, hence I wanted to know if there is a way to import it from an external file and how to handle these with webpack?

Comment: I don't know about webpack, but saving your image as a png or jpg file and setting your css to `url('yourFile.png')` should work ;-) More seriously, why do you use dataURI version ?

Comment: Or you can use two .css files. One file includes all the styles. And other file just includes base64 images for the relevant styles.

Comment: @Kaiido doing it that way will result in additional http requests + I want my image to be loaded as together with stylesheet.

Comment: You know about cache right ?, the benefice to include it directly in the CSS is like nothing, you'll avoid one http request on first load, but your image will be heavier by 35% due to the b64 encoding. Also, you probably heard about load-event, and since you tagged your question with [tag:javascript], I guess you won't be afraid to use some to detect when your images have loaded in order to trigger a class letting know your css you're ready to show the content.

Comment: @Kaiido I believe that cons of base64 images are smaller than pros of eliminating FOUC (js is not an answer - it's only different kind of FOUC)

Comment: @Everettss, if in the head of your html you have a script that will set something like `document.documentElement.style.display = "none";`, and then when your images have loaded, trigger a `document.documentElement.removeAttribute('style')`, there won't be any FOUC. *Beware, one should not do exactly this, others method implying covering the layout, then gracefully reveal what was hidden is probably a better option ;-)* So yes, js can be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack's [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack/url-loader) is made exactly for this purpose!

To configure it, just add this to the loaders of your webpack-config:

```
{
  test: /\.(svg|jpg|png|gif)$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=10000',
}
```

URL-loader returns a data URI for the file you require/import if it's size is below the specified limit, otherwise it bundles the file and returns the URL.

The limit is specified in bytes, so 10000 will roughly mean any file under 10kB will be returned as a data URI. If you specify no limit, everything will be encoded as data URI. I suggest you only use it for small files, however.

So, once it's set up, `var smallImageUri = require('./smallImage.png');` should give you exactly what you need! A data URI if `smallImage.png` is below your configured limit, or the URL to the bundled image when it's larger.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using gulp-css-base64 plugin that will read all images from folders where your images are located. Each time you run gulp task it will update css file with new images (or update current ones).

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/css/input.css')
        .pipe(cssBase64({
            baseDir: "../../images",
            maxWeightResource: 100,
            extensionsAllowed: ['.gif', '.jpg']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```